# Can the spell Make Whole be used to remove the "timeworn" condition from technological items?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I am about to start running the *Iron Gods* adventure path, so I have been reading up on technology in Pathfinder.  Upon reading about timeworn items, my immediate response was, why wouldn't the technomancers of the Technic League just *make whole* such items rather than having a prestige class ability to make them function as if they weren't timeworn?  Why jury rig an item rather than magically fixing it completely?

I understand the game balance, meta-reason for saying no, this doesn't work, but I want to be prepared to be able to give more than just GM fiat (which always leaves a bad taste in players' mouths) for why their good (and in my mind, obvious) idea won't work.  So if there is any official ruling, errata, etc. out there that will back up prohibiting a magical quick fix, I would appreciate it being shared.  Otherwise, I will be forced to either admit the Technic League are **complete** idiots and allow the players to fix every timeworn item they find with a simple 2nd-level spell, or not let it happen because I say so.  (I don't see my players being happy with that reason any more than children are when their parents use it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Make Whole can't remove the timeworn condition

My argument here is based on a simple reading of the rules text. Make Whole can do the following:

- Heal damage
- Remove the broken condition
- Fix destroyed magic items

The timeworn condition is not one of those things. Thus, Mending, Make Whole, and Greater Make Whole have no effect on the timeworn condition. If they find an item that was entirely destroyed before it became timeworn, that's a whole other factor; an item destroyed a long time ago can be restored just fine with Make Whole or Greater Make Whole.

From a more lore-based point of view: The timeworn condition represents something deeper that is wrong with the item than just being broken, the item has been fundamentally changed by the ravages of time. The Mending spell says that "This spell has no effect on objects that have been warped", and nothing in Make Whole or Greater Make Whole says anything to countermand that. When an item has been slowly changed over decades or centuries, it takes more than a single low-level spell to fix it.

Comment: I am aware of what the rules and spells **don't** say.  I'm hoping to have a ruling or errata to point to in order to counteract arguments without having to rely purely on my authority as the GM that when *greater make whole* says it can "fix destroyed magical or technological items" that a "fixed" item would not be restored to fully working state, and thus, lose the timeworn condition.  I'm looking for any official word that might exist or any other rulings that have been made on similar issues.  I want to avoid "it doesn't say you can, so you can't" as I try to encourage creative magic use.

Comment: Your point about the fundamental change made by the ravages of time is a very good one, and if I don't end up having any sort of more direct ruling or errata to use, I will probably rely on that as my reasoning with my players.

Answer (score 2):

[@DuckTapeAl's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/151323/can-the-spell-make-whole-be-used-to-remove-the-timeworn-condition-from-technol/151329#151329) made me aware of the existence of *greater make whole* (I had just skimmed the magic section of the *Technology Guide* previously looking for spells my players might encounter or want to be able to use during their first adventure).

In the process, I noticed and read *memory of function* for the first time.  It appears to be an even more powerful member of the *mending*/*make whole* series, and it has the specific limitation "If you attempt to cast this spell on an object or construct that has been destroyed for more than 10 years per caster level, the spell fails."

As the *Divinity* crashed on Golarion over 9,000 years ago, it would be easy to interpret the above limitation to say that *mending*/*make whole*/*memory of function* **can** remove the timeworn condition, but it would take a caster of over 900th level to be able to do it.  (Or maybe, if you're generous, 800th level if you say it took at least the first 1000 years to cause the timeworn condition in the first place.)

Comment: James Jacobs (although not an official source, he tends to be a good one) [agrees with this assessment](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rwb8?Does-Greater-Make-Whole-remove-the-Timeworn)